# Didnt print on Procedure on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

So I try to print a message when I have any confirmation or error. I have this table [Friendship] that have the ID, friend mail, their mail and the date that have been confirm the friendship,

**Table without data**

[image: 1]

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.pFriendship @Usermail varchar(50), @Friendmail varchar(50) As
    if((Select COUNT(1) From Friendship) < 50)
    begin
        if(@Usermail = @Friendmail)
        begin
            print 'You can not be your friend.';
        end
        else
        begin
        begin TRAN
            Insert Into Friendship (Date, Mail, Friend_Mail) VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), @Usermail, @Friendmail)
            if(@@ERROR <> 0)
            begin
                print 'Fail!';
            end
            print 'User ' + @Usermail+ ' is now friend of ' + @Friendmail;
            commit TRAN;
        end
    end
    else
    begin
            print 'You can not have more friends.';
    end
```

When I use the EXEC for this PROCEDURE, I have the insert values, but not the print´s acctions... Also, If I try to use the same mails, also insert the values. Didnt check the condition

`EXEC dbo.pFriendship 'mailTest@hotmail.com', 'mailTest2@gmail.com'`

**Confirm insert without any use of Print of my PROCEDURE**

[image: 2]

What I was hoping for is like

```
(1 row affected)
User mailtest@gmail.com is now friend of mailtest2@gmail.com
...
```

Or the error at `@@ERROR` or the equals mails error (if applied)

Comment: what do you expect to do with those messages? They aren't results so they can't be used by clients (not without some tricks)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Im gonna connected with my MVC project, and those messages is for my confirmation of some possible errors, but the didnt show up

Comment: And once again, how do you expect to read them? They aren't results. There are several problems with this code too - INSERTs are atomic, they don't need transactions. If the emails are identical - don't call the stored procedure to begin with. If INSERT fails, you'll get an exception in the client code anyway. In short, simply executing `INSERT` would be better

Comment: And what about the count? The User only can have <= 50 friends... P.S Im new on SQL, sorry

Comment: There are several issues with your code e.g., naming a field 'Date'; the number of friends is not linked to the specific user, but a total number in the table; and the success message also comes after a fail. However, I made a table with the fields and used your code above, and it printed the results fine for me.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle (plsql)?

Comment: @jarlh the question was clearly marked as `sql-server` from the start. Someone added `pl/sql` later, although the syntax is clearly T-SQL

Comment: @Tyron78 that won't help at all. Functions *can't* modify data. This isn't even about returning something - `SELECT '...'` would do that, or the OP could use a return or out parameter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos damn, you are right - sorry... somehow confused it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the last else

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.pFriendship @Usermail varchar(50), @Friendmail varchar(50) As
if((Select COUNT(1) From Friendship) < 50)
begin
    if(@Usermail = @Friendmail)
    begin
        print 'You can not be your friend.';
    end
    else
    begin
    begin TRAN
        Insert Into Friendship (Date, Mail, Friend_Mail) VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), @Usermail, @Friendmail)
        if(@@ERROR <> 0)
        begin
            print 'Fail!';
        end
        print 'User ' + @Usermail+ ' is now friend of ' + @Friendmail;
        commit TRAN;
    end
end

begin
        print 'You can not have more friends.';
end
```